# Select a specific word or words within an html tag with REGEX

Tags: php, regex

Hello I am currently trying to get the word **--** but only her so I can replace her in the future. But my problem is I find this inside the input and would just like to select it within the span tag and not the one inside the input.

With this case I do not have control of html to be able to manually modify I need to change this using regex. The output html I have is like this:

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-radio"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="escolher_pacote" value="English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editor -- use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search">
    <span> English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editor -- use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search </span>
  </label>
</span>
<span class="wpcf7-list-item">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="escolher_pacote" value="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting -- Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy">
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting -- Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
    </span>
  </label>
</span>
```

The regex I've tried so far for the knowledge I have are these:

`(--)[^<>]*?<.+?>`

`<span[^>]*>(.*?)</span>`

`>(.*?)\<`

`(--)[^<>]*?<.+?>`

Since I don't have much notion of regex I'm having trouble getting it right. Just to remember I need to select only **--** that is within any spam tag that may or may not contain class and other attributes

i'll use this with php's **preg_replace** function

Comment: Use `DomDocument` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
<span.*?>.*?(--).*?<\/span>
```

https://regex101.com/r/i1EVbR/1